# Running in same child process two times

Tags: c, linux, fork

Can I be running in the same child process two times in the same fork? Ex.

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0){
    some code here
}else{
    some code here
}
wait(NULL)
if (pid ==0){
    some code here
}else{
    some core here
}
```

Comment: The code outside the `if/else` runs in both the parent and child.

Comment: This is what i want to achive: In the first if i want to run the child code first, then pass a value to the parent thru a pipe, check in the parent if the value is ex = 0, and pipe again to the child the message "value is 0" or "value is ~=0" and print it to the child

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the `if/else`, the code runs in both the parent and child. The next `if/else` again switches to different code in each.

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0){
    // child code here
}else{
    // parent code here
}
wait(NULL) // runs in both
if (pid ==0){
    // more child code here
}else{
    // more parent code here
}
```

Unless the child forks another child, `wait(NULL)` in the child will return immediately (it will return `-1` and set `errno` to `ECHILD` to indicate that it has no children to wait for). But in the parent process it will wait for the child to exit. So the second `if/else` block will run immediately in the child, while it will not run in the parent until the child exits.